# Add company logo on the UPS shipping label

Tags: php, api, ups

I have integrated the UPS shipping API in my site which allows the user to create the  shipping labels and take an print out of it,

the label is been created and the users can also print the label , however the label is getting generated which is basically an image file that is returned from the code that i am using but i also wanted to add the company logo on it , please let me know how can i do it.

- Following is the code i have used to create the label

  ```
   function create_shipping_label($shipping_digest) {
   // SHIP ACCEPT REQUEST
   $xmlRequest1 = '<?xml version = "1.0″ encoding = "ISO-8859-1″?>
   <AccessRequest>
  <AccessLicenseNumber>' . UPS_ACCESS_LICENCE_NUMBER . '</AccessLicenseNumber>
  <UserId>' . UPS_USERNAME . '</UserId>
  <Password>' . UPS_PASSWORD . '</Password>
  </AccessRequest>
  <?xml version = "1.0″ encoding = "ISO-8859-1″?>
  <ShipmentAcceptRequest>
  <Request>
  <TransactionReference>
  <CustomerContext>Customer Comment</CustomerContext>
  </TransactionReference>
  <RequestAction>ShipAccept</RequestAction>
  <RequestOption>1</RequestOption>
  </Request>
  <ShipmentDigest>' . $shipping_digest . '</ShipmentDigest>
  </ShipmentAcceptRequest>
  ';

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, PREFIX."ups.com/ups.app/xml/ShipAccept");
  // uncomment the next line if you get curl error 60: error setting certificate   verify locations
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  // uncommenting the next line is most likely not necessary in case of error 60
  // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlRequest1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3600);
  $xmlResponse = curl_exec($ch); // SHIP ACCEPT RESPONSE


  $xml = $xmlResponse;



  preg_match_all("/\<ShipmentAcceptResponse\>(.*?)\<\/ShipmentAcceptResponse\>/s",     $xml, $bookblocks);


   foreach ($bookblocks[1] as $block) {
     preg_match_all("/\<GraphicImage\>(.*?)\<\/GraphicImage\>/", $block, $author);    // GET LABEL
    preg_match_all("/\<TrackingNumber\>(.*?)\<\/TrackingNumber\>/", $block, $tracking); // GET TRACKING NUMBER



  // ( $author[1][0] . "\n" );
  ```

  }

  ```
           return '<img id="shipping_label_image" src="data:image/gif;base64,' .    $author[1][0] . '"/>';
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using laser labels, you would simply need to return additional HTML with the company image above or below the shipping label image.